# Websocket : Making web-socket listeners highly available?

Tags: java, websocket, apache-zookeeper, java-websocket

**Background** :

I have a use-case where i need to ***consume*** a web-socket stream
: *wss://stream.xyz.com:port/stream*

I already have a basic setup up and running (a single instance 'A' is listening to the stream), but want to make this listener service HA (auto Failover incase my listener server 'A' goes down).

**Question** :

Are there any well structured solutions/libraries around the same. 1 tempting option i see here is using zoo-keeper. But reaching out to the community to understand if there are already some other well defined practices/abstractions around the same problem.